# What is a ‘100 feature’ mentioned in One class SVC, and Two class SVC?

Tags: algorithm, azure, machine-learning

I started learning when and where the algorithms for machine learning applied. For anomaly detection algorithms, if you look at Azure machine learning algorithm cheat sheet, it says, “100 features”, so does the same for Two class SVC under classification. What does 100 feature mean in both of the algorithms?
[image]

Comment: Please look more closely: it's not "100 feature", it is simply an indication of " **>** 100 features", i.e that you can use more than 100 features in the respective algorithm (One-class SVM)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look more closely: it's not "100 feature", it is simply an indication of " > 100 features", i.e that you can use more than 100 features in the respective algorithm (One-class SVM)... – desertnaut